# i need Update Query from Mssql to Mysql in LINKED Server

Tags: mysql, sql-server

Actually i need to connect Mssql to Mysql , Fortunately i did with MSSQL 2008 R2 linked server i made connection for Mysql

Now i want to write some queries for update at a time in both databases
when i am trying this query

```
update products set Stock=A.Stock from
  (Select * FROM OPENQUERY(MYSQL,'Select * From products where Id=8')) A
  inner join products B on b.Id=a.Id
```

the rows of MSSQL is updated from MYSQL

i need to update MSSQL to MYSQL also

please help me out ,i am working since last 4 days

Comment: Is the UPDATE example in the documentation unclear? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188427.aspx

Comment: i didn't get you what you are saying..!!

Comment: I understand that have created a linked server on MSSQL that points to  a MySQL database. You can already update MSSQL with data from MySQL, but you do not know how to update MySQL with data from MSSQL. The documentation I suggested shows an example of using UPDATE with OPENQUERY to update data in another server from MSSQL, which is exactly what you are asking how to do. Therefore my question is, since the documentation already answers your question, what difficulty or problem do you have following it?

Answer (score 6):

**MYSQL TO MSSQL UPDATION:**

```
update products set Stock=A.Stock from
(Select * FROM OPENQUERY(MYSQL,'Select * From products')) A
inner join products B on b.Id=a.Id



UPDATE employee
SET LastName = ( Select FirstName from employee where FirstName = (SELECT * FROM
OPENQUERY(MYSQL, 'Select FirstName from employee where IndividualId=3')))
```

**MSSQL TO MYSQL UPDATION:**

```
UPDATE OPENQUERY (database, 'SELECT Stock FROM wings.products WHERE id =1') 
SET Stock=999;
```